# I imported an SVG file, and wanted to color individual parts of my logo, how can i disconnect two parts?

Tags: color, svg

I imported a .svg file into blender, made it 3d, and now I would like to put two individual colors on the logo. The problem is that the two parts I want to be different colors are connected. How do I disconnect them to color individual parts (The red lines is where I want to disconnect them) [image: The red lines is where I want to disconnect them]

Answer (score 0):

just select all the vertices of one part, then hit P -> selected

but...

you can also use another material on the same object by just adding another material, select that material, then select in edit mode the faces you wanna paint, and hit assign.

[image]

Comment: THhanks but when I hit P, it shows separate and not selected, and even if I color one of them, they all turn the same color.
Can you help me please?

Comment: if you select vertices (in edit mode of course) and hit p, this should appear: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RWSHG.png

Comment: Look, https://imgur.com/ewc9V4o

Comment: @Chris It is an imported SVG, so it's a curve object as long as it is not converted to a mesh (and the screenshot shows it is not). There you have not the same menu for separating parts. And you cannot assign different materials to different parts of a curve.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann, So what do I do ?

Comment: @pax First of all convert the curve object to a mesh object, but how to give materials to different parts of an object etc. will be a completely new question... and actually I think when you do not know how to give materials to a mesh you should probably watch some beginner tutorials on materials, texturing etc.